# Не получается авторизоваться по ssh ключу на github

Tags: git, ssh-key

Не получается авторизоваться по SSH ключу. Делал по инструкции:

1. В папке F:\.ssh создал пару ключей
2. Успешно добавил код из публичного ключа в настройках пользователя на github.com
3. Также в папке .ssh создал файл config с кодом:

```
Host github.com
  IdentityFile F:\.ssh\09-06-2020 //путь к приватному ключу
```

Если в консоли выполнить:

```
ssh -T -i F:\.ssh\09-06-2020 git@github.com
```

То авторизация проходит успешно, гитхаб пишет мой логин
а если выполнить команду:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

То ответ приходит такой: git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
И соответственно не могу выполнить команду гита `git push -u origin master` для нового репозитория (remote корректно прописал)

Подскажите, что я сделал не так? Ранее уже успешно добавлял ключи по этой инструкции на другом ПК

Comment: выполнив команду ssh -vT git@github.com , понял что путь в файле config  добавляется к пути на диске C:/user/  . Понимаю, что если перенести ключи туда на диск С, то все должно заработать. Но что, если я хочу чтобы ключи хранились именно по указанному мною пути в config? как тогда там прописать путь?

Answer (score 1):

Перенес ключи в папку C:/user/.ssh и все заработало, т.к. путь к другому диску через файл config изменить не удалось